# Kubernetes config editing

Tags: kubernetes, yaml

Is there any CLI tools or libraries that allow to update container images (and other parameters) in K8S YAML/JSON configuration files?

For example, I have this YAML:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
<...>
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: dmp-reports
          image: example.com/my-image:v1
<...>
```

And I want to automatically update the image for this deployment in this file (basically, this is necessary for the CI/CD system).

Answer (score 2):

We have the same issue on the [Jenkins X](https://jenkins-x.io/) project where we have many git repositories and as we change things like libraries or base docker images we need to change lots of versions in `pom.xml, package.json, Dockerfiles, helm charts` etc.

We use a simple CLI tool called [UpdateBot](https://github.com/jenkins-x/updatebot) which automates the generation of Pull Requests on all downstream repositories. We tend to think of this as Continuous Delivery for libraries and base images ;). e.g. here's the [current Pull Requests that UpdateBot has generated on the Jenkins X organisation repositories](https://github.com/pulls?q=is%3Apr+archived%3Afalse+user%3Ajenkins-x+is%3Aclosed+label%3Aupdatebot)

Then here's how we update Dockerfiles / helm charts as we release, say, new base images:
https://github.com/jenkins-x/builder-base/blob/master/jx/scripts/release.sh#L28-L29

Answer (score 0):

You can use [sed](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/x23170.html) in your CI/CD pipeline to update the file and deploy. In jenkins its `sh sed .....`.

You can also use [Helm](https://docs.helm.sh/helm/) - create templates and you can specify the new image names (etc.) when deploying the release.

Comment: I know about Helm, but it not suitable for this case: I want to always have up-to-date cluster configurations in VCS (with versions). `sed` is ok, but I want to use more accurate tool